# capturing each word containing pattern regex

Tags: regex, sed

I'm trying to write a sed script that finds every word that contains a certain pattern and then prepends all words that contain that pattern. For example:

```
foobarbaz barfoobaz barbazfoo barbaz
```

might turn into:

```
quxfoobarbaz quxbarfoobaz quxbarbazfoo barbaz
```

I understand the basics of capture groups and backrefrences, but I'm still having trouble. Specifically I can't get it so that it captures each whole word separately.

```
s/\(.*\)men\(.*\)/ not just the \1men\2, but the \1women\2 and \1children\2 too /
```

I tried using `\s`, for whitespace as many sites recommend, but sed treats `\s` as the separate characters `\` and `s`

Comment: Why specifically sed?

Comment: @glennjackman SO wanted another tag, plus I'm not sure if there were some context dependent considerations I should take into account. regex isn't the same everywhere.

Comment: `\s` is GNU shorthand for the POSIX character class `[:space:]`, most commonly used in a bracket expression, e.g. `[[:space:]]`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the non-space character `\S` as follows:

```
sed 's/\S*foo\S*/qux&/g' <<< "foobarbaz barfoobaz barbazfoo barbaz"
```

this will match words containing `foo`. The replacement string `qux&` will prepend every matched pattern with `qux`. Output:

```
quxfoobarbaz quxbarfoobaz quxbarbazfoo barbaz
```

Comment: I get `quxfoobarbaz barquxfoobaz barbazquxfoo barbaz` when I use that.

Comment: Perhaps your sed's version does not support `\S`. Try replacing `\S` with a character class `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`

Comment: `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` isn't a character class, it's a bracket expression containing ranges and lists of characters. `[:alnum:]` is a character class which is typically used in a bracket expression as `[[:alnum:]_]` to denote "word-constituent-characters". The equivalent of `\S`, though, is `[^[:space:]]`.

Comment: I was not aware of the difference between character class and bracket expression.  Thanks for clarifying this point.

Answer (score 0):

It works fine if no spaces in each word.

```
echo "foobarbaz barfoobaz barbazfoo barbaz" | sed 's/\([^ ]*foo[^ ]*\)/qux\1/g'
```